# App to work in background?

Tags: java, android, android-service

I am creating an accident detection app that senses the user's activity. I want the app to run even when the app is closed as accidents need to be detected. Is it possible to do that or should the app be open for the sensors to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `Services` https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.

Depending on what kind of accidents you're detecting I'd advise to keep an eye on Doze mode. Doze mode switches off sensors when the device is in stand by mode.